# Regex - Phone numbers or empty space not working

Tags: regex

I have this regex for phone numbers in New Zealand:

```
^\+?[\d\s\(\)]{1,14}$|^((\+?64\s*[\(]?2\d{1}[\)]?|\(?02\d{1}\)?)\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3,5})$
```

[image]

I want to allow an empty string as well so I do what the internet says to do (add `^$|` to the front):

[image]

As you can see it makes most of the passing numbers fail. It does the same thing when I add brackets to the front.

How do I allow empty strings and also phone numbers using the expression at the top of this question?

Please copy paste this into [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) to experiment with possible solutions:

expression:

```
^\+?[\d\s\(\)]{1,14}$|^((\+?64\s*[\(]?2\d{1}[\)]?|\(?02\d{1}\)?)\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3,5})$
```

Text:

```
Positive:
021 755 2375

+79261234567
9261234567
+1234567
89261234567
4035555678
23423
3454
021 2343234
926 3 4
1 416 555 9292
926 1234567
495 1234567
+7 555 1234567
+7(926)1234567
(926) 1234567
469 123 45 67
0800 345345786
09 419 7555
0800 475 4669
202 555 4567

Negative:

027 .343 -454
8 800 600-APPLE
+42 555.123.4567
926.123.4567
64 25 .435 -34323
025 .435                        -343
123-4567
123-89-01
+1-(800)-123-4567
8 (926) 1234567
415-555-1234
650-555-2345
(416)555-3456
09-419 7555
364563456345645643565346768
```

Comment: Isn't it matched, just nothing to capture? https://regex101.com/r/afxv6D/1

Comment: @chris85 It isn't working in Regexr.com as shown by the photo. Why is there nothing to capture? I have the text to capture.

Comment: Empty is nothing, or it is to me. Where are you using this, how do you plan to represent empty? I'm not familiar with `regexr.com` I've always used regex101 or my actual language. Are you having issues with your actual implementation?

Comment: @chris85 This is used on a website front end with javascript. I haven't tried to implement it in code yet as I was thinking I haven't yet finished the regex expression, but it seems I may have. I will try to implement it in the app.

Comment: It seems to work as a JS expression as well on regex101, https://regex101.com/r/afxv6D/2. I'd try it out, if it works update your bookmark to regex101. This seems to be an application issue, not programming.

Comment: regex101 > regexr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grouping:

```
(?:^$)|(?:^\+?[\d\s\(\)]{1,14}$|^((\+?64\s*[\(]?2\d{1}[\)]?|\(?02\d{1}\)?)\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3,5})$)
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oDHL9z/1)

Comment: Thanks. In regexr.com it doesn't work, and has an error saying that it matches infinitely. Is this nothing to worry about?

Comment: As you may know, there are many flavors of regex. PCRE, GNU Grep,Perl, and Python will be able to use that Regex; JavaScript, Java, other may not. I think that is more of an regex.com issue...

Comment: The grouping doesn't add anything, does it?

Comment: Clarity and, potentially, clarify precedence of `|` being lower than either the RH or LH group. Perl and PCRE -- agreed, it is already that but the re engine was not specified...

Comment: I didn't know there were different flavours of regex but I'm using javascript. I find the bracket grouping a bit more readable though and it works as far as I can tell - code seems to be rejecting and passing text as expected. Cheers